# Can you recursively construct a finite cover for an arbitrary product of compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology

I read that Tychonoff's theorem says that the arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact (i.e. using the product topology). Most of the proofs use nets and ultrafilters along with the finite intersection property (Munkres's Chapter 5). Some proofs show a contradiction using the well-ordering theorem (an exercise in Munkres's book and others in the internet).

But am wondering if there have been any proofs of construction to create the finite cover for the infinite product of compact spaces ... For instance, let $X$ be:

$
X = X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_i \times ...
$

where $X_i$ is compact for all $i$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open covering of $X$, we can try to recursively construct a finite subcovering $\mathcal{C}$ for $X$ from $\mathcal{A}$ by doing the following:

At the start, the collection $\mathcal{C}$ is empty. For step $1$, use the compactness of $X_1$ to create a finite cover $\mathcal{A_1} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ for $X_1$ such that $\bigcup_{S \in \mathcal{A_1}} \pi_1(S) = X_1$ (where $\pi_i$ is the usual projection function). Then set $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{A_1}$.

For the next step, given that no open set $S = S_1 \times ... S_i \times ...$ in the product topology has infinitely many indices $i$ such that $\pi_i(S) \neq X_i$, it follows that the total number of indices $i$ such that $\bigcup_{S \in \mathcal{C}} \pi_i(S) \neq X_i$ is also finite (using the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ is a finite collection). Collect these indices as a finite set $\{i_1, i_2, ... i_N\}$. We can then repeat the procedure above for $X_{i_1}$ (with $i_1 \neq 1$) to create a finite cover $\mathcal{A_2} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ for $X_{i_1}$ and include it in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{A_1} \bigcup \mathcal{A_2}$. This is repeated up to $i_N$ so that $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{A_{i_1}} \bigcup \mathcal{A_{i_2}} \bigcup ... \bigcup \mathcal{A_{i_N}}$.

Since $|\{i_1, i_2, ..., i_N\}|$ is finite and each $\mathcal{A_{i_j}}$ is finite for $j=\{1,2,..,N\}$, it follows that $\mathcal{C}$ is a finite collection of subsets that cover $X$. For any $X_m$ such that $m \not \in \{i_1, i_2, ..., i_N\}$, we have that $\mathcal{A_1}$ covers them completely since $\pi_m(S) =X_m$ for any $S \in \mathcal{A_1}$ and for any $m \not\in \{i_1, i_2, ..., i_N\}$.

But I am not seeing this type of proof in all of the textbooks so there must be something wrong here ... What am I missing here ?

Comment: Tychonoff's theorem is provably equivalent to the axiom of choice, so no too-"explicit" argument can possibly work.

Comment: Pretty sure this is essentially a duplicate but the key error is that knowing $\pi_i(U)=X_i$ for all $i$ does not imply that $U$ has to be all of $X$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I seem to see what you mean, but just to check that am getting the right intuition, could you please give a simple counterexample ? thanks a lot

Comment: Consider the set $\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, for instance.

Comment: @EricWofsey, oh right ! if you write this down as an answer, I'll accept it thanks

Comment: Tychonoff's theorem applies to uncountable products, where it's impossible to iterate over the entire index set. That's what nets are for, to handle index sets that are bigger than sequences.